# How to style a span with a checkbox input

Tags: javascript

I was trying to style a span attached to a checkbox input with JavaScript. It is working but when refreshing the page on input checked, the applied style is not maintained.

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector("#new");

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {

  if (checkbox.checked) {
    document.querySelector("#newFilter").style.backgroundColor = "#272727";
    document.querySelector("#newFilter").style.color = "#ffffff";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#newFilter").style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    document.querySelector("#newFilter").style.color = "#272727";
  }

});
```

```html
<input class="" type="checkbox" id="new" name="new" value="New">
<label class="" for="new" id="">
  <span id="newFilter">English Language</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the styles to persist when you exit or refresh the page you have to store the checkbox's value somehow. Browsers don't just store a page's data as it was left, you have to find a way to retrieve and store data yourself.

One way to do that is with [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). But it's important to understand first how each of those work and what are the appropriate use cases first.